# Java Regex to remove hash from before words

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I want to replace a word starting with # in a string which contains set of words with the same word (# omitted)

example

"word1 word2 **#user**" should be replaced with "word1 word2 **user**"

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is your string something like `#user` or like `#user #word #anotherWord...` ?

Comment: do you just want to remove the # attached to a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use regex. Lets start with

```
yourText = yourText.replaceAll("#(\\S+)", "$1");
```

in regex:

- `\S` represents any non-whitespace characters
- `+` represents *one or more*
- `\S+` represents one or more non-whitespace characters
- `(\S+)` -parenthesis create group containing one or more non-whitespace characters, this group will be indexed as `1`

in replacement

- `$1` in replacement allows us to use content of group 1.

In other words it will try to find `#non-whitespaces` (which and replace it with `non-whitespaces` part.

But this solution doesn't require `#` to be start of word. To do this we could check if before `#` there is

- whitespace space `\s`,
- or start of the string `^`.

To test if something is before our element without actually including it in our match we can use look-behind `(?<=...)`.

So our final solution can look like

```
yourText = yourText.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\s)#(\\S+)", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

```
String foo = "#user"
foo = foo.replaceAll("#", "");
```

Comment: This will remove all `#` regardless where they are.

Comment: @IsurangaPerera `replace` also replaces *all* occurrences of searched text. Only difference between `replace` and `replaceAll` is that `replaceAll` is using regex syntax, while `replace` uses literals.

Answer (score 0):

You have not very clear use case, but my assumptions with code example:

1. omit all symbols with *replaceAll* function
2. omit just first symbol  with *substring* function

   public class TestRegex {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String omitInStart = "#user";
       String omitInMiddle = "#user";
       String omitInEnd = "#user";
       String omitFewSymbols = "#us#er";

       List<String> listForOmit = Arrays.asList(omitInStart, omitInMiddle, omitInEnd, omitFewSymbols);
       listForOmit.forEach(e -> System.out.println(omitWithReplace(e)));

       listForOmit.forEach(e -> System.out.println(omitFirstSymbol(e)));

   }

   private static String omitFirstSymbol(String stringForOmit) {
       return stringForOmit.substring(1);
   }

   private static String omitWithReplace(String stringForOmit) {
       String symbolForOmit = "#";
       return stringForOmit.replaceAll(symbolForOmit, "");
   }
   ```

   }